# Drag and drop lists and virtual repeaters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop, angular-material, angulardraganddroplists

I need to create sortable drag and drop lists in my application. So, for this I have used [angular-drag-and-drop-lists](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists) which works fine for an small amount of items.

However, my application migh have thousands of items. So, to improve speed, I need to use [md-virtual-repeat](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat) offered by `Angular Material`. It keeps the model in the background with the right number of elements. But, the DOM only renders those that are visible within a virtual container.

Because the library uses the rendered `$index` to keep track of the elements, using the virtual repeater creates all sort of problems since the `$index` now is virtual.

Some of these problems for instance are:

- Dragged element gets duplicated in the `model`
- Element that was in drop location gets deleted from the `model`
- During dragging some elements might get lost from the original `model`
- Etc...

What do you suggest to attack this problem?

Are there any other easier solutions rather than using this library?

Thank you